Oracle Data Pump Export (expdp) how to exit if invalid credentials and not wait to provide valid one?
Execution:
Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu May 9 07:58:59 2024
Version 19.20.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDE-01017: operation generated ORACLE error 1017
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Username:    <-- program awaits and doesn't exit

I want expdp to exit in case of invalid credentials provided. How to do that?
Command used:
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/expdp $CONNECT_STRING \
  SCHEMAS=$BACKUP_NAME \
  DUMPFILE=${BACKUP_FILE_DATA}_%u.dmp \
  LOGFILE=${BACKUP_FILE_DATA}.exp \
  JOB_NAME=${BACKUP_FILE_DATA} \
  DIRECTORY=SOME_BACKUP__ \
  CONTENT=ALL PARALLEL=4 METRICS=YES LOGTIME=ALL \
  QUERY='BP_LOG_PLSQL:"WHERE 1=0",...' \
  QUERY='BP_AUDIT_LOG_PRC:"WHERE 1=0",...' \
  QUERY='BP_QUEUE_READER_HISTORY:"WHERE 1=0",...' \
  QUERY='BP_BLOCKED_SESSION_LOG:"WHERE 1=0",...' \
  QUERY='BP_RPT_CUST_COMP_MV_$1:"WHERE 1=0"
...
,BP_RPT_RND_PKGG_MV_$2:"WHERE 1=0"
' \
  EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"LIKE \'%2018%\'\" \
  EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"LIKE \'%2019%\'\" \
  EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"LIKE \'%2020%\'\" \
  EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"LIKE \'%2021%\'\" \
  EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"LIKE \'%2022%\'\" \
  EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"LIKE \'%2023%\'\" \
  EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"LIKE \'%2024%\'\" \
  EXCLUDE=TABLE:\"LIKE \'XXX%\'\"


can you share the whole expdp command please

@paganini expdp command provided
